# Simple doubt about Cauchy and convergent sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Everything that follows below is under the context we are working on normed vector spaces.

**Some context.** When trying to prove a subspace $S \subset X = (X,\| \cdot\|_X)$ is closed, the first intuition would be to show that $S = \overline{S}$, where $\overline{S} = S \cup S'.$ The inclusion $S \subset \overline{S}$ comes simply by definition of $\overline{S}.$ Normally, the only thing one has to do is to show that $\overline{S} \subset S$ and thus the subspace $S$ is closed.

To do so, we pick an arbitrary element of $\overline{S}$, say $s \in \overline{S}$ and certainly there is a convergent sequence $(s_k)_{k \in \Bbb N} \subset S$ such that $s_k \rightarrow s$, as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

It is also well known that every convergent sequence is also a Cauchy sequence and here urges my question. We know that the sequence $(s_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence where each element is in the subspace $S$ and at the same time it converges to an element $s \in \overline{S}.$

**Can we say $(s_k)_ {k\in \Bbb N}$ is a cauchy sequence in $S$ or/and can we say that $(s_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is a cauchy sequence in $\overline{S}$? If so, why?**

In other words, if a sequence is defined in a set $S$ but converges to a point **not necessarily** in $S$ is it a Cauchy sequence on $S$?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This is in a sense the whole point of distinguishing Cauchy sequences from convergent sequences: the sequence is Cauchy in $S$ even if it converges to a point not in $S$ (that is, it doesn’t converge in $S$). The definition of a Cauchy sequence only looks at terms in the sequence (which are all in $S$); it doesn’t care about the whether/where the limit exists.

Comment: So basically, given a convergent sequence $(s_k)_{k \in \Bbb N} \subset S$ (doesn't matter where it converges to) we can say that $(s_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequnece in $S$?

Comment: Yes, but if you say the sequence is convergent in $S$ then that implies that the limit is actually in $S$. If the limit is not in $S$, then the sequence is not convergent in $S$. Convergence is not a property just of sequences, but of sequences in spaces. For instance, the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in $[0,1]$ but not in $(0,1]$. But it is Cauchy in both $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$: being Cauchy doesn't depend on the space the sequence is in, since the existence of the limit is irrelevant and all that matters is the distance between the terms in the sequence itself.